# Chrome cant show image when using cellular data. but working fine when using wifi

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, google-maps

i try to open my website where there is some function to get current location and show the image of my location.

but its only working when im using wifi data and when im using cellular data the image got blank.

any suggest why this happen??
its problem from my iphone or from my website??

Answer (score 2):

If other images work on your iPhone on cellular, the problem most probably is on your web site.